# how to display static html files using iron router

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I want to render normal html files using iron router.however when i try to do that its showing me other template instead of the template i am attaching it using iron router.

this is my main layout

```
<template name="mainLayout">

{{> yield region="navBar"}}

{{> yield}}

{{> yield region="footer"}}

</template>
```

This is how my router.js file looks like

```
Router.route('/',{
  name: 'root',
  controller: 'MainPageController'
});
Router.route("/:_id",{
  name: 'signlePost',
  controller: 'singlePostController'
});

Router.route("/about", function(){
  this.render("aboutUs")
});
```

this is the template i want to render

```
<template name="aboutUs">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p> 
</template>
```

however instead of rendering the appropriate aboutUs page its rendering singlePost template again on aboutUs page. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it is the best way, but that should solve this.

1. Create a controller `about_us_controller.js`for your html file.

   ```
   this.AboutController = RouteController.extend({
   template: "aboutUs",
   action: function() {
      this.render();
   }
   });
   ```
2. Declare it in your `router.js`

   `Router.map ( function () {`

   `this.route("aboutUs", {path: "/about", controller: "AboutController"});`

   `//add all the other routes`
   `});`

ps: I couldn't get the code displaying properly, sorry

3. You can now access your 'aboutUs' template using, for instance, `{{pathFor 'aboutUs'}}` in, e.g., a link `href` attribute

Comment: maybe the map function was overkill. Just use `Router.route("/about", { name: 'aboutUs',  controller: 'AboutController '});` in your `router.js`

Comment: I tried that also, but it just doesn't work. i don't understand why

Comment: its still doing the same thing. still yielding that singlePost template instead of aboutUs template.

Answer (score 1):

switch order in which the routes are declared, because you `signlePost` route patterns also matches "/about".

```
Router.route("/about", function(){
    this.render("aboutUs")
});
Router.route("/:_id",{
    name: 'signlePost',
    controller: 'singlePostController'
});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but there is another problem. its showing me error when iam trying to connect it to my BaseController which holds mainLayout template i.e in base.js i have `BaseController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate : 'mainLayout'
});`  and in about_us.js `AboutController = BaseController.extend({
  template: "aboutUs"
});` and its showing me reference error BaseController is not defined however it is working with other controllers that i have like PostController

Comment: The files are included in alphabetical order. Could you rename your base.js to 0base.js and try?

Comment: so stupid of me. It worked thanks alot. but is it recommended to name it in this way?

Comment: Since the files are included in the alphabetical order, if a different file in the same folder references a particular variable, you should ideally prefix it with a numerical so that that file gets included first. I'm not too sure if is recommended, but it is a good solution.

Comment: that's a regular workaround. if you want to make it prettier, name it `0_base` and apply the numerotation to the other files. You should validate @kaoskeya answer.